# Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 - replica VMs state "password incorrect", but lets me log in after 7-8 minutes

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, login, windows-authentication

so I have a replica server that backups 2 server 2012 R2 VMs. Each week, I run a test failover to make sure they boot up, and I can log into them. A curious issue I'm having is, once I get to the login screen, I can type the password to login, only to get the "password is incorrect" message. This will happen every time I try.

However, after about 7 or 8 minutes of the replica VM running, I can type in the same password, and it logs me in. Is there maybe a service that's delayed in starting up that would cause this issue?

Comment: Is this a local or domain account? Did the password recently change?

Comment: Domain account. The VMs are domain controllers. Password has not changed.